# Is there a Linux analog to the Clipmate I use in Windows?

Tags: clipboard

In Windows, I use a program called Clipmate.
It harvests text and images from the Windows clipboard.
It has an archiving utility, a search utility, and editing functions (e.g., find and replace).

Is there any analog to Clipmate in the Unbuntu universe?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I am aware of is Glipper (or Klipper in KDE).

These both only function for text.